# Images appear when variable gets high enough

Tags: javascript, html, increment

So in my game i want a way of kind of leveling up. (html and java script game) So when you get to 1000 in allCount a picture appears. A animal picture appears. An then when you get to 100000 in allCount a new image appears. Kind of like acheivments, but pictures. Like you need to collect all the animal pictures. My game animal clicker: http://jsfiddle.net/blosche/T4zL3/14/

The allCount (The thing tht needs to get too 1000 to show a new picture)

```
var score = document.getElementById('allCount');
score.innerHTML = "Animals: " + allCount;
```

Comment: Nice, but what's the problem you're having with it?

Comment: Nice knock-off of the cookie clicker :P

Comment: I just do not know how to do it. I researched and can not find it.

Comment: So, a spin-off of the [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) game with animals? I guess it makes more sense than the original one :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy to do using `if` statements.

It is reasonable to assume that you have to recalculate the value of the `score` variable at least once per second. So every time you retrieve the `score` value, use `if` statements to do some basic comparison:

```
if(score >= 1000) {
    //show a picture
}
```

If you want the picture only to be shown once (for example, the first time the user breaks a score of 1000), then you can set a `BOOL` value in the `<body onLoad="">` method like this:

```
<body onLoad="setBools">
<script type="text/javascript">
function setBools() {
    var hit1000 = FALSE;
}
</script>
```

Then:

```
if(score >= 1000 && !hit1000) {
hit1000 = TRUE;
//show a picture
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

It seems like you're having some trouble displaying the picture, based on your comments. Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="myimage.png" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

JavaScript:

```
if(score >= 1000) {
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

So the image is by default not visible, but then once you get a score of greater than or equal to 1000, the image is visible.

Comment: if(score >= 1000){
      <img src="http://i788.photobucket.com/albums/yy168/Boone_Losche/th_MomObject_zps20d68d83.png" alt="level1"/>
      }

Comment: See the updated post. And you need a better foundation in your knowledge of programming, you can't just mix HTML and JavaScript like that.